# Why 'mutating table error' is run time?

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently in an interview I was  asked what is 'mutating table error'.
I told it occurs when a row level trigger has a dml query on the same table. 
Then the interviewer asked if this is the case then it should be complie time error as the compiler knows that the trigger has a dml query on the same table.

Comment: I don't understand what the interviewer is getting at. Indeed, the mutating table error SHOULD BE a compile-time error; but Oracle decided not to check for it at parse (compile) time. For comparison: `select 1/0 from dual` throws a runtime error, not a compile time error. The compiler knows at compile time that I am dividing by 0, but it doesn't throw an error. Because Oracle didn't write the "compiler" (the parser) to check for that error while it is parsing the query. Simple as that.

Comment: @mathguy, perhaps Oracle wants to permit this case by intention: [Why am I NOT getting a mutating table error in trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202925/why-mutating-table-error-is-run-time)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a trigger. The error is *'ORA-04091: table XYZ is mutating, **trigger/function** may not see it'*. You can get it from a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple reason that a trigger contains any kind of logic you want to have in it.

For example, if the trigger had:

```
if :new.start_date > sysdate + 1 then
  select ... [my bad dml that would cause a mutating table error]
end if;
```

then should it not compile? For all we know, that IF condition might never evaluate to true, and this the offending DML would never be run.